# how to print max (item_bought_count)?

Tags: sql, mysql

I was solving question 5 of case-study-1 of 8-week-sql-challenge by Danny. I am stuck at this point. I have written following code

```
select
  customer_id,
  product_name,
  count(sales.product_id) as 'item_bought_count',
  dense_rank() over(partition by customer_id order by count(sales.product_id) desc) as 'purchase_rank'
from sales
join menu on sales.product_id = menu.product_id
group by customer_id, sales.product_id ;
```

and it is giving following output

[image: My_Output]

but I need following output

[image: Correct_Output]

the Question : Which item was the most popular for each customer?

In this query as you can see expected image, I want to print max item_bought_count  of product for each customer.I sorted all this using dense rank. Now i just have to take out rows having dense rank =1 for each customer. I cannot figure how to do that. Any suggestions how to do that ?

one thing more: I am writing query in mysql workbench, so it is quite different from sql server solutions and help available on intenet

Comment: There is no difference in SQL Server and MySQL here; you'd right the very same query. Single quotes denote string literals, not names, so you should for instance replace `as 'item_bought_count'` by `as item_bought_count` in either DBMS.

Comment: Is it true for naming columns, Kettner ? I thought it is necessary to use single or double quotes, though I prefer singles rather than doubles.

Comment: Don't mix single and double quotes. They have different meanings in SQL. Single quotes are for string literals, e.g. `where col = 'abc'`. Double quotes are for names, e.g. `select col as "Name" from mytable`, but we try to avoid double quotes whenever possible and use names for expressions, columns and tables instead that need no quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT customer_id, product_name, item_bought_count
FROM (
    SELECT 
        customer_id,
        product_name,
        COUNT(sales.product_id) AS item_bought_count,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY COUNT(sales.product_id) DESC) AS purchase_rank
    FROM sales
    JOIN menu ON sales.product_id = menu.product_id
    GROUP BY customer_id, sales.product_id
) AS subquery
WHERE purchase_rank = 1;
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. It doesn't have to be much text, just some words explaining what your query does. E.g. "select from your query result`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks for pointing out, from onwards I will post the code with explanation also.